# Twilio - Unable to set SmsApplicationSid for an IncomingPhoneNumber resource

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am working on configuring Twilio messaging using the Twilio api with `Subaccount`s and `MessagingService`s.

I am able to create a `MessagingService` and an `IncomingPhoneNumber` using the Twilio api. However, if I attempt to set the `SmsApplicationSid` for the `IncomingPhoneNumber` to the sid of the `MessagingService`, I receive the following error:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Application not found for sid: <--REDACTED-->",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/400",
    "status": 400
}
```

The `more_info` url (https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/400) gives me a 404 not found which is not helpful.

I have tried setting the `SmsApplicationSid` both when first creating the `IncomingPhoneNumber` resource, as well as in an update after first creating the `IncomingPhoneNumber` without the `SmsApplicationSid` value. Both approaches respond with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation isn't clear on this, but I decided to try adding the `IncomingPhoneNumber` to the `MessagingService` and that worked.

Url:
https://messaging.twilio.com/v1/Services/{smsApplicationSid}//PhoneNumbers

Method:
Post

Header:
"PhoneNumberSid", {incomingPhoneNumberSid}